# I can't create a fixed position using css "<div style='position: fixed'>" not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to enter Adsense code under a fixed position on the side bar so that it scrolls with the page. 
I am trying

```
<div style='position: fixed'>
    adsense code
</div>
```

The Adsense ad works fine without the css code however when i add the div it goes blank and nothing shows. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could be a "quote" issue.

Comment: First google result: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/yg6vhGFhapQ - It is against AdSense policy

Answer (score 1):

You should add width and height settings to that DIV, otherwise (with `position: fixed`) it will be 0x0 = invisible.